# Method loadVideoFromAsset must be called from UI thread

Tags: android, virtual-reality, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

I am trying to implement 360 Video Viewer in my project but I am getting an error for the line:

```
mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options);
```

This is the error

```
Method loadVideoFromAsset must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred 
thread is worker
```

Following is my code:

```
package com.example.jal.jp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoEventListener;
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView;

import java.io.IOException;

public abstract class VR_Video extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private VrVideoView mVrVideoView;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private Button mVolumeButton;

    private boolean mIsPaused;
    private boolean mIsMuted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vr__video);

        initViews();

    }
    public void onPlayPausePressed() {

    }

    public void onVolumeToggleClicked() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

    }

    private void initViews() {
        mVrVideoView = (VrVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        mVolumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_volume);
        mVrVideoView.setEventListener(new ActivityEventListener());
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mVolumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onVolumeToggleClicked();
            }
        });
    }
    class VideoLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
                options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
                mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options);
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                //Handle exception
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
    public void playPause() {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mVrVideoView.pauseRendering();
        mIsPaused = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mVrVideoView.resumeRendering();
        mIsPaused = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mVrVideoView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    private class ActivityEventListener extends VrVideoEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onLoadSuccess() {
            super.onLoadSuccess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadError(String errorMessage) {
            super.onLoadError(errorMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            super.onClick();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNewFrame() {
            super.onNewFrame();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion() {
            super.onCompletion();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help. I tried my best but couldn't fix.

Comment: Call This  VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
                options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
                mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options); out side of AsyncTask. Don't call it in doInBackground.

Comment: Where  to write outside?I tried but to no avail. I am newbie to Android, trying to learn. If you can add it to my code and show then that would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where You Are Calling VideoLoaderTask.execute()? Try those three lines call immediately after "mVrVideoView.setEventListener(new ActivityEventListener());". Not in do in background.

Comment: I did as you said., but it showing one error. "Unhandeled exception Java.io.IOException"

Comment: You have to put it in try and catch like this                                            
          try {
                VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
                options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
                mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options);
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                //Handle exception
            }

Comment: thanks. there is no more error.

Comment: I gave it as answer. Tick it if you feel helpfull.

Comment: I am not able to find the tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove AsyncTask Implementation And Call Required Methods From UI Thread**

Use Below Code :

```
private void initViews() {
    mVrVideoView = (VrVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
    mVolumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_volume);
    mVrVideoView.setEventListener(new ActivityEventListener());
    try {
            VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
            options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
            mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options);
        } catch( IOException e ) {
            //Handle exception
        }
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mVolumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onVolumeToggleClicked();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about videoview but I show in your code that you are trying to access some the features in doInbackground method. The doINbackground method runs on a separate thread from the UI thread so that complex ant time consuming tasks do not block the UI thread. You can implement the features you are implementing in doINbackground method in the onCreate method or if you still need to use doInbackground you can access the UI thread inside doInbackground using  runOnUiThread as follows

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //your code here
                    }
                });`

Comment: thanks. can you  please show me excatly where to put the block of code you gave.

Comment: protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //your code here
                        VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
                        options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
                        mVrVideoView.loadVideoFromAsset("sea.mp4", options);
                    }
 I am getting an error. Unhandeled exception Java.io.IOException.

Comment: cannot help you with these much information. You need to provide your code and the log errors.